# Find the area of the parts formed from the parabola $2y=2-x^2$ separating the circle $x^2+y^2 \leq 5$?

Tags: analysis

Find the area of the parts formed from the parabola $2y=2-x^2$ separating the circle $x^2+y^2 \leq 5$?
I know the standard method when we are given equations,but what we do when we have inequalities?

Comment: The inequality $x^2+y^2 \leq 5$ defines a *solid* circle with radius $\sqrt{5}$ centered at $(0,0)$ in the cartesian plane. The equality $x^2+y^2 =5$ defines just the perimeter of that same circle. Computationally speaking, I don't think this will change anything.

Comment: I will be happy if you show me how the integral should look,because the integral i form seems to be inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality $x^2+y^2\leq 5$ gives the inside of the circle. The boundary is given given by the equation  $x^2+y^2 = 5$. Draw a picture and it should be clear. You can solve it with the equation of the circle as the circle is bounding the area from below (so you need to choose negative sign, if you want to calculate the lower part, that is).

Here's a picture to aid the geometrical thinking:

[image: circle and parabola]

The red lines are the "radii" (lines $y=\frac{1}{2}x$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}x$. Yellow area is the one you must solve with integration. Notice that it's symmetrical, so the area you want is twice the yellow area in the picture. The green sector you get with the formula of the area of a sector, angle (in radians) over $2\pi$ times the area of the whole circle.

Comment: So  x is between -2 and 2 and (2-x^2)/2<=y<=(5-x^2)^(1/2)?If so the integral seems to a little bit awful.

Comment: Yes the circle part might be a bit tricky to do in rectangular coordinates. You can also use geometrical ways to calculate the area. Draw a couple of radii from the origin (center of the circle) to the intersection points and notice you have a sector and a couple of parts where the bounds are a line and a parabola.

Comment: According to WA the answer of the integral made from (2-x^2)/2<=y<=(5-x^2)^(1/2) is too complicated to be true.I think the answer should be an exact number........so i am open to suggestions.

Comment: @Guest25 What's wrong with the exact number $\frac{10}{3} +5\sin^{-1}(\frac{2}{\sqrt 5})$? You arrive to this also with the geometrical argument (when you solve the angle of the sector you must take arcussine there). This is the area of the lower part. It's easier to calculate this since $y$ solved from the circle equation is a function of $x$ there. It isn't in the upper part.